# Why is last-child not targeting the last article tag in this fiddle?

Tags: css, html, article

Why is last-child not targeting the last article tag in this fiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/gunP9/

```
<div class="parent">
<article class="example">111</article>
<article class="example">111</article>
<article class="example">111</article>
<article class="example">111</article>
<section>content</section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent .example{ background-color: red;}
.parent .example:last-child{background-color: yellow;}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`last-child` targets, well, the last child of the parent. In this case, the last child is a `section` which doesn't have the class `example`, and consequently nothing matches the selector.

What you're looking for is `last-of-type`, which matches *elements* and not classes. [Take a look.](http://jsfiddle.net/y3kA8/)

Comment: grumble .. it doesn't work with ie8 ... do you know any other way other than JS?

Comment: scratch that ... last-child wouldnt have worked with IE8 anyway :-O

Answer (score 0):

Because the selector says "last child of each of articles"

Comment: How do it get it to target the last article? ie not section